# using fbox in a newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments, minipage, framed

I am trying to write a new enviroment to add text into a \fbox, when I use \fbox on its own, it works quite nicely

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
does this work, I would love if it did
\end{minipage}}
```

If I then add this into a new comand called notes Latex dosen't seem to like it

```
\newenvironment{notes}
{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}}}
{\end{minipage}}
```

When I then enter something into this environment in my document it comes up with errors

```
\begin{notes}
Does this work, I would love if it did
\end{notes}
```

The error I recieve is:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\fbox ...xsep {#1}\kern \fboxsep \color@endgroup }
\@frameb@x \relax 
l.80 \begin{notes}

?
```

Comment: Is there any reason you NEED it in an environment form?  It is simple to just make it a macro `\newcommand\notes[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}}`.  Then the usage is `\notes{Does this work, I would love if it did}`

Comment: This was the motivation for adding `lrbox` in latex2e, see the fbox/lrbox example on page 13 of `usrguide` (`texdoc usrguide` in texlive at least or http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/usrguide.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This shows how to do it in both macro (`\notes`) and environment (`\begin{Notes}`) forms.  EDIT: Thanks to jfbu for the proper syntax that allows one to avoid environment nesting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{Notes}
{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}}
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}

\newcommand\notes[1]{%
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}
\notes{Does this work, I would love if it did}

\begin{Notes}
Does this work in an environment form?  I would love if it did
\end{Notes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, works a treat!!! I am now trying to add a figure environment inside the note environment, I can add an image through \includegraphics but would ideally like an image, is there a away of doing this or does latex not allow an environment in an environment?

\begin{Notes}
Does this work in an environment form?  I would love if it did
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{testimage}
\caption{testimage is lena}}
\label{fig:lena}
\end{figure}
Doesn't like this...
\end{Notes}

Comment: is there a reason for not doing all the job in the `Notes` environment?

Comment: @jbfu For some reason, the box wasn't available for use within the inner box (it came up blank), so I nested it.  I perhaps did something inefficiently.

Comment: in the `Notes` environment I can't get `\caption` to work, comes up with the following error `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`, it allows me in insert the graphic and `centering` is applied to the whole environment, not just the figure

Comment: @cjm in general, environments within environments can sometimes be tricky, depending on the environment.  I would think `figure` is tricky, because it is a float.

Comment: It works with `\newenvironment{Notes}`
`{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}}`
`{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}}`

Comment: @jfbu  Thanks for the correction.  Applied.